# Generate unique random alphanumeric using javascript

Tags: javascript, random

code:

```
function alphanumeric()

{

var randomnum=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,8);

document.getElementbyId("textBoxId").value = randomnum;

}
```

Each time when I call alphanumeric() function this will generate alphanumeric random string and show on the Text Box like.. v3ta4t8l,zshqoc2u,9pey71rb...which works fine..
In my requirement I need to allow only unique alphanumeric. Could you please help me to solve my below question,

1.Is it only generate unique alphanumeric?

2.How many alphanumeric this will generate?

3.Is it possible to allow only unique alphanumeric?

4.It is possible to store unique alphanumeric in database use of primary key in my case already one of my column having primary key and so I will try to implement with the use of java script...

Comment: Have you ever heard of GUIDs?

Comment: sorry..I do not have enough idea about that...

Comment: I have looked at the answers and your question and I'm not sure what exactly you mean by unique. Do you want no repeated characters within one string or do you want to emit a series of unique strings when you call `alphanumeric()` repeatedly?

Comment: I don't need to show any repeated same value...sorry for the inconvenient..

Comment: Related: [how to generate uuid in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that would return only unique alphanumerics

```
function alphanumeric_unique() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter( function(value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }).join('').substr(2,8);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/arGg9/5/)

Splitting the string into an array of characters, then using `Array.filter()` to filter out any characters that are already in the array to get only one instance of each character, and then finally joining the characters back to a string, and running `substr(2, 8)` to get the same length string as in the question, where it starts at the second character and gets a total of eight characters.

Comment: Thanks..adeneo... could you please tell me, How many alphanumeric this will generate?

Comment: @user3333029 - It will generally exactly as many as the original function does, as it uses substr() after the duplicate alphanumnerics have been weeded out.

Comment: Once again thanks... adeneo... let me know could you please little bit text about this code. I am beginner.Hope that will more helpful to me...

Answer (score 1):

```
 function IDGenerate() {
        var text = "";
        var hdntxt = "";
        var captchatext = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIkLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));         
        }

        document.getElementById("txtboxID").value = text;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to `splice` the used character out of `possible` after you've used it?

Comment: For that We Should use System GUID only.It is very bad idea to check every time to database when it is generated or else we can keep some Formats like Time+Username it also creates uniqueness.Time can get in Javascript and If user logged in session value can be get in Javascript. both can combine and go ahead for Uniqueness.